# Pragmatic Programmer: avoid data source duplication by using map?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

In the Pragmatic Programmer book, chapter “Data source duplication” the authors state:

> Many Data sources allow you to introspect on their data schema. This can be used to remove much of the duplication between them and your code. Rather than manually creating the code to contain this stored data, you can generate the containers directly from the schema. Many persistence frameworks will do this heavy lifting for you.

So far so good. We can achieve this easily connecting our IDE to the DB and let it create our entities for us.
Then it continues:

> There’s another option, and one we often prefer. Rather than writing code that represents external data in a fixed structure (an instance of a struct of class for example), just stick it into a key/value data structure (your language might call it a map, hash, dictionary, or even object). On its own this is risky .... we recommend adding a second layer to this solution: a simply table-driven validation suite that verifies that the map you’ve created contains at least the data you need. Your API documentation tool might be able to generate this.

The idea if I got it right is to avoid having an Entity to represent the table in the DB (so to avoid duplication of knowledge) but rather to use a map, so that if we add a new column to the schema we don’t need to update our representation of that schema (i.e. the entity) as well in our application.

Then comes the part that is not clear to me: he talks about an autogenerated “table-driven validation suite that verifies that the map you’ve created contains at least the data you need”.

Does any of you know how these concept implemented would look like?
The closest thing i could find on Google about this topic is [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/419213/how-to-avoid-duplication-with-data-sources) on StackOverflow but the answers skipped the second part.

Answer (score 0):

I think it really depends on the language you’re using and on the data you need to read. For Java, if you’re mapping the raw data to a Map what you could do is to use validators (ex Hibernate validators or spring validators) to define your custom annotation and enforce that schema’s constraints are respected when creating the in memory representation (eg: you’re reading a user table with id as primary key, the map must then contain the id key with a valid value)